# Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest' i am unable to build the app

Tags: android, manifest

`Error: Cannot find declaration of element manifest`
I have the `<manifest></manifest>` element in `my AndroidManifest.xml` still I am getting the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.anupsaha.streammusic">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<application
android:name=".MyApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_round"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<activity
android:name=".SplashActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity
android:name=".BaseActivity"/>

<activity
android:name=".RegisterActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

<activity
android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

<activity
android:name=".ProfileActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"/>

<activity
android:name=".ProfileEditActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

<activity
android:name=".ReportActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"/>

<activity
android:name=".SuggestionActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"/>

<activity android:name=".SongByCatActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"/>

<activity android:name=".SongByServerPlaylistActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity android:name=".SongByMyPlaylistActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity android:name=".SongByOfflineActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"/>

<activity android:name=".SongByOFFPlaylistActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity android:name=".Add2OfflinePlaylistActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity android:name=".SettingActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity android:name=".AboutActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity
android:name=".OfflineMusicActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing" />

<activity android:name=".SelectSongActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"/>

<activity android:name=".MiniPlayer"
android:theme="@style/Theme.MiniPlayer"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:taskAffinity=""
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="content" />
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<service
android:name=".PlayerService"
android:exported="false" />

<service
android:name="com.anupsaha.utils.NotificationExtenderExample"
android:exported="false"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

<service
android:name=".DownloadService"
android:exported="false" />

<receiver android:name="com.anupsaha.utils.MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

AndroidManifest file link - [here is link](https://justpaste.it/59wv2)

Comment: post your manifest file !

Comment: https://justpaste.it/59wv2

Comment: 1. clear .idea file in project folder and try to rebuild it.
if 1. not working, try 2.
2. delete build folder and rebuild project

Comment: for add code in post, use ``` code, n lines ```